# C: prefix in #include

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Let's say we have two C projects in directories `project1` and `project2`, each having their own `include` directory.
Is it possible for a source in `project1/src` to include a header file from `project2` like this: `#include <project2/def.h>` where `def.h` exists in `project2/include/def.h`?

Thanks.

Edit: to make it clear, let's say you have these two projets:

```
project1/
  - Makefile
  - include/def.h
  - main.c

project2/
  - Makefile
  - include/def.h
  - main.c
```

the questions is, can you **in project1** refer to headers **of project2** with such an include (in `project1/main.c` for example):

```
#include <project2/def.h>
```

The answer is no, as is.

Comment: Files are not exclusive to the project they belong, so yes. Consider it as an aggregation relation

Comment: Use an absolute file path or even a well-constructed relative file path in the Include statement and also consider using the " " delimiters on the file name if you build that tricky relative file path.

Comment: You might also want to look at the `-I` flag in gcc/clang and `/I` in MSVC

Comment: Also the exact case you have mentioned won't work because the source file is in project1/src. You will have to use ../../

Comment: @cup, please read fully until you understand the real question instead of answering with a zero entropy comment. Thanks.

Comment: @friedrich A [mcve] by you would also have been helpful.Then, in my opinion, your question qualifies for upvotes, instead of downvotes, because it shows the "research".  And you might consider taking the [tour] to get the badge for it. Sometimes it puts readers/answerers in a more helpful mood if they see that badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

technically, no you can't *as is*.

if you really want:

```
#include <project2/def.h>
```

but have `project2/include/def.h`, you have two ways to handle that:

if you compile with `-Iproject2/include`, then you create a subdirectory and place your header there:

```
project2/include/project2/def.h
```

which you'll include from project1 as `#include <project2/def.h>`.

Or, you can create the header `project2/def.h` that will contain `#include project2/include/def.h` and you'll call `-I.` where `.` is the directory above `project2` sources.

The better solution, in my humble opinion, is the first one, as it doesn't rely on knowing how you named your `project2` sources directory (it could be named foobar locally, you'll still be able to `-I/path/to/foobar/include/` and `#include .

Comment: That's what I thought, too bad we can't namespace include directories.

Comment: Can't you just kludge up a file path in the include statement regardless of where the header file is?

Comment: @nicomp I think you would end up either having absolute paths (which I consider "evil") or relative paths across project folder structures (which I consider nothing better).

Comment: @Yunnosch Copy that.